# Downloading mp3 files using python, often getting corrupt

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, download

I have written a python script using web scraping modules to download Youtube videos as a mp3 file

```
import requests,os,re
import bs4
homedir=os.path.expanduser('~')+'\\Music\\'
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')

def getDetailed(url):
 videoUrl = {'video': url}
 responce = requests.get('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/',    params=videoUrl)
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(responce.content, 'lxml')
 videoTitle = soup.find('span', id='videoTitle').text
 videoTitle=regex.sub('',videoTitle)
 try:
  videoLink = soup.find('a', id='download')['href']
  vidList.append([videoTitle,rawUrl+videoLink])
 except:
  print(videoTitle+' could not be downloaded')


def getTheList(videoListUrl):
 global folderName
 url='https://www.youtube.com'
 soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(videoListUrl).content,'lxml')
 folderName=soup.title.text
 links = soup.select('a.pl-video-title-link.yt-uix-tile-link.yt-uix-sessionlink.spf-link')
 print(len(links),'videos found')
 for link in links:
  getDetailed(url+link['href'])

def download():
 directory = homedir+folderName
 if not os.path.exists(directory):
    print('creating diretory')
    os.makedirs(directory)
 print(directory)
 i =1
 for name,link in vidList:
  if os.path.exists(directory+'\\'+name+'.mp3'):
      print('skiping '+name+' songs   remaining:',len(vidList)-i)
      i=i+1
  else:
   video = requests.get(link)
   with open(directory+'\\'+name+ '.mp3', 'wb') as writefile:
    writefile.write(video.content)
   print('video downloaded, check it out.        Remaining videos:',len(vidList)-i)
   i=i+1

vidList=[]
folderName=''
rawUrl='http://www.youtubeinmp3.com'
#asking for url,for testing I am keeping a list a default
videoListUrl=str(input('enter the playlist link'))
getTheList(videoListUrl)
print(len(vidList),'vides are ready to download')
download()
```

This code downloads all videos in the youtube playlist depending on [this](http://www.youtubeinmp3.com) website.
It's working fine, but some corrupt errors i.e. if there are 10 songs on the list, at least 2 of them would be corrupted files.

[image]

So, I would like to know why some of them not correctly downloading. Is my code wrong, or what will happen?

Comment: You could try recoding your get call to use streaming,e.g `requests.get(..., stream=True)` . Then use `for chunk in video: ; writefile.write(chunk)`

Comment: I agree with Martin, you should stream your requests. You can refer here - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests